# Monitor the amount of blobs entering into an Azure container

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-blob-storage

Basically I have a storage account with a containers that contain blobs of unhandled errors. My task is to somehow generate a metric that will be able to show how many blobs were uploaded to that container every hour. I tried using the Azure built in metrics, but it seems like that might limit me to the entire storage account and not just one container. I did some research on Power BI and thought that might be a good place to start, but again I came up empty.

If anyone has a good *starting place* for me, that would be incredible. I'm assuming that this will end up being something that requires some SQL queries, or perhaps something I can do programatically in Visual Studio. Apologies if this was posted in the wrong place, but it seemed like the best fit from my opinion.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at `Azure Event Grid with Blob Storage Integration`. In short, whenever a blob is created, an event will be raised by Azure Event Grid. You can consume this event and post the event data to an HTTP endpoint (or call an Azure Function) which can save this information about this event in some persistent storage (Azure Tables for example). You can then create reports by querying this data.

For more information about this, you may find this link helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-event-overview.

Comment: I think this is the way to go, but I still haven't gotten it to work quiiiiiite yet. I'll mark it as the answer when I get it to work though. Thanks!